# Underscore не читает шаблон

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, шаблонизаторы, underscore.js

Есть код:

```
BookApp.Views.KeyWord = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    initialize : function(){
      this.render();      
    },
    render : function(){
      console.log(this.model.toJSON());

      this.$el.html(_.template("( -<%= name %>- )",this.model.toJSON()) ); 
      console.log(this.el);
      return this;
    }
  })
```

Дальше происходит вызов этой модели и в итоге вот console.log:
[image: console.log() кода, указанного выше]

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему "name" не подхватился?
Заране спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже что вы не понимаете как работают шаблоны в Underscore. Прежде чем выводить шаблон, его нужно скомпилировать. Для этого и предназначен метод [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) - для **компиляции** шаблона, а не для вывода.

В вашем случае, если вы не хотите хранить скомпилированный шаблон в переменной, вы можете использовать такой код:

```
...
render : function(){
    _.template( "( -<%= name %>- )")(this.model.toJSON() );
    ...
}
...
```

Впрочем, в этом случае шаблон будет компилироваться **каждый раз** при вызове `render`, что не очень эффективно. Поэтому лучше хранить скомпилированный шаблон внутри экземпляра View и вызывать как метод:

```
...
template: _.template("( -<%= name %>- )"),
...
render : function(){
  console.log(this.model.toJSON());

  this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) ); 
  console.log(this.el);
  return this;
}
...
```

Comment: Получается метод _.template(tpl) возвращает функцию, которой передаются данные для вставки. 
Это называется замыканием в JS?

Comment: _Получается метод _.template(tpl) возвращает функцию, которой передаются данные для вставки._ Так и есть. _Это называется замыканием в JS?_ Можно и так сказать. Хотя в вашем случае это не имеет никакого значения.

Comment: Просто для понимания механизма. Спасибо.